# Calculate surface of a triangle

Tags: triangles, surfaces

It's quite a simple question solvable with many methods but the $2$ of them I picked don't agree.

First of I have chosen the triangle with corners: $(3,0,0) \quad (0,3,0) \quad (0,0,6)$

Thus, this one here:

[image]

First Method is by evaluating the surface Integral: $A = \int_{S}1\,\mathrm{dS} = \int_{(u,v)}1\,|n|\,\mathrm{du\,dv}$

As parametrization I came up with: $\psi(u,v) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}3\,u\\ 3\,v \\ 6-6\,u-6\,v\end{array}\right) \quad u \in[0,1] \quad v \in [0,1] \quad u+v<1$

Hence $n = \partial_u\psi \times \partial_v\psi = \left(\begin{array}{cc}18\\ 18 \\ 9\end{array}\right)\quad$ $\Rightarrow \quad  \displaystyle{A = \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-u}} \sqrt{2\cdot18^2+9^2}\,\mathrm{dv\,du} = 13,5$

Next Method is by using straight geometry: $A=  \frac{1}{2}\,g\,h$ (base times hight)

It should be: $A = \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt{3^2+3^2}\,h = \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt{18}\,\sqrt{6^2+\left(\sqrt{3^2-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{18}}\right)^2} \approx 13,9$

Now again, where does this difference come from? Probably one could check by calculation $\textbf{det}$

Comment: The first method is giving the correct answer - for the second method you should just have $$h=\sqrt{36+\frac{18}4}$$

Comment: Oh Right , I simply forgot squaring >_< . Thank you for reminding.

Comment: Your drawing doesn't match the coordinates. Shouldn't be $(3,0,0)$ instead of $(0,0,3)$?

Comment: I fixed stupid mistakes in my answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have:
$$A = \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt{3^2+3^2}\,h = \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt{18}\,\sqrt{6^2+\left(\sqrt{3^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{18}\right)^\color{red}{2}}\right)^2} =13.5.$$

Or you can note that the triangles at the base are isosceles:

[image]

So $AC=BC=\frac{\sqrt{18}}{2}$ is what you need:
$$A = \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt{3^2+3^2}\,h = \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt{18}\,\sqrt{6^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{18}}{2}\right)^2} =13.5.$$

Alternatively, you can use Heron's formula:
$$a=3\sqrt{2},b=c=3\sqrt5,\\
S=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}=\\
\sqrt{\frac{3\sqrt{2}+6\sqrt5}{2}\cdot \frac{6\sqrt{5}-3\sqrt2}{2}\cdot \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}}=\\
\sqrt{\frac{162\cdot 18}{16}}=\frac{27}{2}=13.5.$$

Answer (score 1):

Given $V=6$ and $S=3$

The length of the triangle base is base is

$B=\sqrt{S^2+S^2}=\sqrt{3^2+3^2}=3\sqrt{2}. \quad$

The distance from the back corner to the base is

$Z=\sqrt{S^2-\bigg(\dfrac{B}{2}\bigg)^2}=\sqrt{3^2-\bigg(\dfrac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}\bigg)^2}
=\dfrac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}.\quad$

The altitude of the triangle is

$H=\sqrt{V^2+Z^2}
=\sqrt{6^2+\bigg(\dfrac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}\bigg)^2}
=\dfrac{9\sqrt{2}}{2}.\quad$

The area of the triangle is

$A=\dfrac{B}{2}H
=\dfrac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot\dfrac{9\sqrt{2}}{2}
=\dfrac{27}{2}=13.5
$

Comment: I'm afraid to tell you that $A = 13,5$ really is the right answer. Interesting approach though.

Comment: You make two mistakes: You correctly calculated $H = \frac{9\sqrt 2}{2}$ but later you substituted $H = \frac{9\sqrt{\color{red}3}}{2}$. But more importantly, once you had found $B$ and $H$, the area of the triangle is simply  $\frac{1}{2}B H$. You don't calculate the area of a triangle as $\sqrt{\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)^2+H^2}$

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks. I must have been half asleep to miss that.